# Error caused after adding XSLT list web part to page with Document Library web part

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, xslt-list-view-web-part

I am trying to apply a xslt list view from one site to a bunch of other sites. This is a filtered calendar web part in list style not calendar view, so I cant use an overlay. I am adding the web part on the landing page of each site. The landing page also has a document library web part on the page.

There are no issues when the web part is added. However once I try to click into folders for the document library the page throws an error. This does not happen with other list view web parts (links, library) that have been added from other sites only once the calendar has been added.

Error that I get from ULS is:

System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range. at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetWebRelativeUrlFromUrl(String strUrl, Boolean includeQueryString, Boolean canonicalizeUrl) at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetItem(String strUrl, Boolean bFile, Boolean cacheRowsetAndId, Boolean bDatesInUtc, String[] fields) at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.EnsureCurrentFolderInfo() at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions permissionMask, Boolean checkFolder) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.RightsSensitiveVisibilityHelper.UserHasRights(PermissionContext permissionContext, SPBasePermissions permissions, PermissionMode permissionMode, SPContext context, SPWeb contextWeb, SPList contextList) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.RightsSensit...

At first I thought this had to do with some custom XSL I had added. However I tried it without the custom xsl and still had the same issue.

Anyone else experience this. I am running this issue with SharePoint 2010 Foundation.

Answer (score 0):

XSL List Views should only be used for lists and libraries on the same site.  The views themselves often seem to work but they can corrupt the source list/library.  The solution I have used in the past to solve this is to delete the offending web part, delete the list/library and then restore from the recycle bin.

To display list/library contents from another site you should use the CQWP, a Core Search web part or potentially create a custom source in the site you want the page linked to the list/library.

Personally, I would use the CQWP.  The concepts of customising the XSL are basically the same though you do need to tweak the properties of the web part to use your XSL files.  I have a post on my blog which goes through this if you need more details - http://paylord.wordpress.com

Comment: CQWP is my preferred method, but I am on SharePoint Foundation as mentioned at the bottom of my post. No CQWP available, though I may have this client on SharePoint Online in the coming months, fingers crossed. I have had plenty of luck with these list views in the past when they have been needed.I am wondering about this server in particular, though I now have it patched to April 2013 CU.

Comment: I have experienced this particular issue a few times over the last couple of years so do not think it is related to a recent patch.  Sorry about the CQWP suggestion - I missed that you were on Foundation.